# Javascript check if href is clicked

Tags: javascript, mobile, click

I have a slider where I need to call some javascript whenever the next button is called. I can't edit the html of the slider itself to add onClick to the html. So I need to check if the a href element is clicked.

I have tried selecting the whole div to make return an alert if the div is clicked this works but when I click on the href on my phone it doens't work.

```
document.querySelector('.wmpci-popup-body a.flex-next').onclick = function() {
   alert("button was clicked");
};

<div class="wmpci-popup-body">
    <ol class="flex-control-nav flex-control-paging">
        <li><a href="#" class="flex-active">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
    </ol>
    <ul class="flex-direction-nav">
        <li class="flex-nav-prev"><a class="flex-prev flex-disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1"></a></li>
        <li class="flex-nav-next"><a class="flex-next" href="#"></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I hope someone can tell me whats wrong with my current code.

Comment: Please show us your HTML where the href is

Comment: Please read on how to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Any code must be placed in your question, as text, not as a picture, preferably as a working code snippet.

Comment: Alright thanks I have added the html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like thedivmeister mentioned, you should use the touchstart and/or click event.
You could do something like this in vanilla:

```
const eventHandler = () => alert("button was clicked");

const element = document.querySelector('.wmpci-popup-body a.flex-next');
element.addEventListener('touchstart', eventHandler, false);
element.addEventListener('click', eventHandler, false);
```

I provided a little codesandbox to test on mobile:
https://codesandbox.io/s/staging-night-fogx3

Answer (score -1):

If you want to restrict default functionality you can add  event.preventDefault();

```js
document.querySelector('.wmpci-popup-body a.flex-next').on('click touchstart', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  alert("button was clicked");
});
```